# OpenLayers.Image positionning difference between kml vs openlayers

Tags: openlayers, kml

I have an issue to correctly positionning an image with  OpenLayers. I have a web software how create KML file or display map on a webpage.

Here a screenshot of a map display on Google Earth and the same display with  openlayers, (Google Earth is the good visualization). 
The map is a bit stretch on the north

[image]
[image]

What is false ? the epsg conversion ? Do I Need to rebuld image with  gdalwarp ?

Here a sample of my code

```
function ConvertLonLatFromESPG4326ToESPG900913(LonLat) {
var lonlatTransforme = LonLat.clone();
if (map == null) {
    lonlatTransforme.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
}
else {
    lonlatTransforme.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection(map.getProjectionObject().projCode));
}
return lonlatTransforme;

}

var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
bounds.extend(ConvertLonLatFromESPG4326ToESPG900913(new OpenLayers.LonLat(y1, x1)));
bounds.extend(ConvertLonLatFromESPG4326ToESPG900913(new OpenLayers.LonLat(y2, x2)));

var graphic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
            nomImage,
            url,
            bounds,
            new OpenLayers.Size($("#map").width(), $("#map").height()),
            {
                //http://www.forumsig.org/showthread.php?t=26393
                maxResolution: map.layers[0].resolutions[0],
                resolutions: map.layers[0].resolutions,                    
                isBaseLayer: false,
                displayInLayerSwitcher: true
            }
        );
map.addLayer(graphic);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Image bounds are wrong. Either the OpenLayers.Layer.Image bounds or the image file bounds. If you are not using the OpenLayers transform function, also ConvertLonLatFromESPG4326ToESPG900913 could be wrong!

Comment: because the image have no border it's difficult to see on capture but on this fiddle you can have more information : http://jsfiddle.net/seb49/cdmsud7m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution, as I thought it had to use gdalwarp.

Here my code to rebuild the image

```
//step1 create a GeoTIFF
gdal_translate.exe  -of Gtiff -co tfw=yes -a_ullr -5.25555900000001 52.739645 10.334585 41.047037 -a_srs EPSG:4326 "D:\imageSource.png" "D:\imageEtape1.tiff"
//step2 redraw GeoTIFF
gdalwarp.exe  -co COMPRESS=LZW -r bilinear -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:900913 "D:\imageEtape1.tiff" "D:\imageEtape2.tiff" 
//step3 transform the geoTiff to PNG
gdal_translate.exe  -of PNG -a_ullr -5.25555900000001 52.739645 10.334585 41.047037 -a_srs EPSG:4326 "D:\imageEtape2.tiff" "D:\imageFinale.png"[/code]
```

I hope this could help someone. (I understand now why OpenLayers, althought it know to parse kml, don't manage groundoverlay because the result will be the same problem that I had